# Beautiful Soup not recognizing Button Tag

Tags: python, button, tags, beautifulsoup, soundcloud

I'm currently experimenting with Beautiful Soup 4 in Python 2.7.6

Right now, I have a simple script to scrape Soundcloud.com. I'm trying to print out the number of button tags on the page, but I'm not getting the answer I expect.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('http://soundcloud.com/sondersc/waterfalls-sonder')
data = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

buttons = soup.findAll('button')
print len(buttons)
```

When I run this, I get the output

```
num buttons = 0
```

This confuses me. I know for a fact that the button tags exist on this page so it shouldn't be returning 0. Upon inspecting the button elements directly underneath the waveform, I find these...

```
<button class="sc-button sc-button-like sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive" tabindex="0" title="Like">Like</button>
<button class="sc-button sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive sc-button-addtoset" tabindex="0" title="Add to playlist">Add to playlist</button>
<button class="sc-button sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive sc-button-addtogroup" tabindex="0" title="Add to group">Add to group</button>
<button class="sc-button sc-button-share sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive" title="Share" tabindex="0">Share</button>
```

At first I thought that the way I was trying to find the button elements was incorrect. However, if I modify my code to scrape an arbitrary youtube page...

```
page = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiyDmqO59QE')
```

then I get the output

```
num buttons = 37
```

So that means that `soup.findAll('button')` is doing what it's suppose to, just not on soundcloud.

I've also tried specifying the exact button I want, expecting to get a return result of 1

```
buttons = soup.findAll('button', class_='sc-button sc-button-like sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive')
print 'num buttons =', len(buttons)
```

but it still returns 0.

I'm kind of stumped on this one. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: The "<button" tags are generated by `javascript` so you can't use your approach. Either use their API or try something like `selenium` to parse the page.  P.S. Great song!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot get the buttons is that there are no `button` tags inside the html you are getting:

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://soundcloud.com/sondersc/waterfalls-sonder')
>>> data = page.text
>>> '<button' in data
False
```

This means that there is much more involved in forming the page: AJAX requests, javascript function calls etc

Also, note that `soundcloud` provides an [API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/) - there is no need to crawl HTML pages of the site. There is also a [python wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python) around the Soundcloud API available.

Also, be careful about web-scraping, study [`Terms of Use`](https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use):

> You must not employ scraping or similar techniques to aggregate,
>   repurpose, republish or otherwise make use of any Content.

Comment: Thanks so much. I also wasn't aware of that clause from the terms of use. Guess I chose a poor website to experiment with. I'll be cognizant of this in the future as I'm sure other websites might employ similar policies.

Comment: @welty yup, the first thing to check is Terms of Use, then look for the API.